# Easiest way to use node.js package from heroku rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, node.js, heroku

Hello railites and jsheads,

I'm a ruby guy and pretty new to the node thing, but I'm learning and so far I really like it. I've been developing a rails app on heroku for a week or so, and (of course) the requirements have evolved.

I need to be able to use [pdfkit](https://github.com/devongovett/pdfkit), a node library for creating pdfs, from my rails app.

Ultimately, I am after the simplest way to accomplish just that. This is what I've tried so far:

From the heroku docs [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline#troubleshooting), I know that heroku rails apps come with a node js runtime, but it seems that npm is not included, and I could not find an obvious way to require pdfkit.

So I followed the the lead on this [blog](http://otobrglez.opalab.com/rails/2014/01/21/bower-rails-heroku.html), using ddollar's multi buildpack:

```
heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi.git
```

Here are snippets form the relevant files (let me know if I am missing something ;) )

.buildpack

```
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "MoneyMaker",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "pdfkit": "0.5.2"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type" : "git",
    "url" : "https://github.com/mattwalters/example.git"
  }
}
```

Gemfile:

```
...
gem 'execjs'
...
```

test.js

```
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.7.1
(function() {
  var PDFDocument, doc, fs;
  fs = require("fs");
  PDFDocument = require('pdfkit');
  doc = new PDFDocument;
  doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('output.pdf'));
  doc.addPage().fontSize(25).text('Here is some vector graphics...', 100, 100);
  doc.save().moveTo(100, 150).lineTo(100, 250).lineTo(200, 250).fill("#FF3300");
  doc.scale(0.6).translate(470, -380).path('M 250,75 L 323,301 131,161 369,161 177,301 z').fill('red', 'even-odd').restore();
  doc.addPage().fillColor("blue").text('Here is a link!', 100, 100).underline(100, 100, 160, 27, {
    color: "#0000FF"
  }).link(100, 100, 160, 27, 'http://google.com/');
  doc.end();
}).call(this)
```

Note I did check node_modules into source control.
I pushed all of this to heroku, and tried to manually call test.js with execjs:

```
matt$ heroku run rails c
heroku-irb> ExecJS.eval(File.open('test.js').read)
```

I get the folloring error:

```
ExecJS::ProgramError: TypeError: undefined is not a function
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/execjs-2.0.2/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:68:in `extract_result'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/execjs-2.0.2/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:28:in `block in exec'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/execjs-2.0.2/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:41:in `compile_to_tempfile'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/execjs-2.0.2/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:27:in `exec'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/execjs-2.0.2/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:19:in `eval'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/execjs-2.0.2/lib/execjs/runtime.rb:40:in `eval'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/execjs-2.0.2/lib/execjs/module.rb:23:in `eval'
    from (irb):3
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:62:in `<top (required)>'
    from /app/bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from /app/bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I tried to simplify and just run:

```
heroku - irb> ExecJS.eval("require('pdfkit')")
```

But I get the same error. I think I am missing something pretty major when it comes to execjs. Can anyone enlighten me?

Then I wanted to see if I could call test.js directly from node. Note this works in my local dev environment.

```
matt$ heroku run bash
heroku$ node test.js
```

But I get:

```
node.js:134
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
        ^
Error: Cannot find module 'zlib'
    at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:320:11)
    at Function._load (module.js:266:25)
    at require (module.js:348:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/pdfkit/js/reference.js:12:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/pdfkit/js/reference.js:101:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:404:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:410:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:336:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:297:12)
    at require (module.js:348:19)
```

So now I'm throwing my hands up and hoping the wisdom of the community can help me. Please let me know if you'd like additional information.

Thanks very much,
Matt

Answer (score 1):

So the problem was that the default buildpack installs a version of node automatically if your application depends on execjs. Unfortunately this is a very old version of node -- 0.4.7 -- that is incompatible with the node libraries I need to use.

My solution was to fork heroku's buildpack and patch the add_node_js_binary method to never install node binaries. This works as long as your multi buildpack configuration includes a node distro. Check it out here:

https://github.com/mattwalters/heroku-buildpack-ruby/blob/master/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb

Comment: Awesome, I'm having this exact problem. As you say, /app/bin is in the environmental PATH variable first and it has node 0.4.7 while another directory later in the PATH has the version of node specified in package.json. Super annoying -- going to go fork your repo and be happy. Thanks!

Comment: BTW, I am still having trouble making ExecJS behave.... See my SO question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22852086/1396827 
Any idea there?

Comment: I'm not sure how to fix that -- I'm actually trying to get a gem to work (browserify-rails) that uses a node module on Heroku during asset compilation.